# an error in the cat example in the book of getting started with laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

my project is:https://github.com/xsmyqf/startlaravel
when I visit `startlaravel/public/cats/create`
I got the error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Trying to get property of non-object 
(View: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\xiestartlaravel\app\views\cats\single.blade.php)
Open: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\xiestartlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php

// an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
try
{
include $__path;
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$this->handleViewException($e);
}
```

Comment: it says $this->handleViewException($e); is an error

Comment: No, it says you're trying to get property of non-object. Show you view.

Comment: I have corrected the error，it is because the two routes are same to laravel that it cannot identify.                 Route::get('cats/{id}', function($id) {
$cat = Cat::find($id);
return View::make('cats.single')
->with('cat', $cat);
});
Route::get('cats/create', function() {
$cat = new Cat;
return View::make('cats.edit')
->with('cat', $cat)
->with('method', 'post');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the error，it is because the two routes are same to laravel that it cannot identify. Route::get('cats/{id}', function($id) { $cat = Cat::find($id); return View::make('cats.single') ->with('cat', $cat); }); Route::get('cats/create', function() { $cat = new Cat; return View::make('cats.edit') ->with('cat', $cat) ->with('method', 'post'); });